# ExpressJS app not serving correct public files for nested routes

Tags: node.js, express, router

## The background

So I have a simple Express app (made with express-generator) with this structure (y show only relevant parts):

```
myapp
├── app.js
├─┬ public
│ └─┬ assets
│   ├── css
│   └── js
├─┬ routes
│ └── admin.js
└─┬ views
  ├── layout.pug
  ├── admin.pug
  └── process.pug
```

#### My views

My layout.pug is something like this

```
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='assets/css/main.css')
        script(type="text/javascript", src="assets/js/main.js")
        block imports
    body
        /*navigation*/
        block contents
```

While admin.pug is

```
extends layout
block imports
    script(type="text/javascript", src="assets/js/admin.js")
block contents
    p Admin page
```

And process.pug is

```
extends layout
block imports
    script(type="text/javascript", src="assets/js/process.js")
block contents
    p Process page
    p= id
```

#### My routes

I have one route file, admin.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/process/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('process', {
        title: 'process page',
        id: req.params.id
    });
}

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('admin', {
        title: 'admin page'
    });
}

module.exports = router;
```

#### My app.js

Relevant things I do in my app.js file are:

```
var admin = require('./routes/admin');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/admin', admin);
```

## The problem

With my app being as I wrote above, my '/admin/ page works wonderfull. BUT when i try to navigate to '/admin/process/id' it doesn't. It wont load any of the resources from my public folder. It tries to load from '/admin/process/assets/' instead of '/assets/'.

## What I've tried

I'm completely lost with this but I've tried a couple of things.

- Creating a `'/admin/process'` route in my actual admin.js file gets the same result (doesn't load resources).
- Creating a completely new route file and *using* it on app.js with `app.use('/admin/process', newFile);` results on same behaviour.

Comment: did you try `src="/assets/js/admin.js"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add absolute path for the files - 
**layout.pug**

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/assets/css/main.css')
script(type="text/javascript", src="/assets/js/main.js")
```

**admin.pug**

```
script(type="text/javascript", src="assets/js/admin.js")
```

**process.pug**

```
script(type="text/javascript", src="/assets/js/process.js")
```

Comment: why did you accept as a answer then?! I mean, is not clear if this answer helped or not

Comment: you have to use **absolute path** i.e path starting from `/assets/css/main.css` they specify the location of a file or directory from the root directory(/). Where as the **relative path** `assets/css/main.css` they specify path related to the present working directory. More info [link](https://www.linux.com/blog/absloute-path-vs-relative-path-linuxunix)

Comment: @MarceloFilho I accepted it because doing what it suggests solved the problem and worked for me

Comment: @Ayush ok I got it. Thank you very much!